# Play specific frames in video using C#

Tags: c#, video, aforge

I am trying to play part of the video(in this example from frame no 1 to frame 299) in c#. I tried with below code, it works perfectly for single frame but does not display anything after addition of loop. The code does not throw any errors.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Open video file
            VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
            reader.Open(@"c:\Users\Replay.avi");

            // Read frame no. 1 to 300 and display in picturebox
            for (int j = 1; j < 300; j++)
             {

                Bitmap replay_frame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
                pictureBox1.Image = replay_frame;
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
```

Whats wrong with the above code?

Comment: _"does not display anything"_ - you mean it's blank? Have you tried stepping through the code? Or adding a delay between setting each frame (because as it is you're not going to be able to see any changes, as the code will run through so fast the images won't have time to be painted). Oh, and I seem to remember you should dispose of the existing image on the PictureBox before assigning a new one..

Comment: Yes, its blank. I tried added delay to make it slower but it didn't work. But after reading your comment I realized , I need to somehow incorporate the frame rate in the code. I will try to play it in the windows media player instead. My objective for doing this is to play video from certain frame or time. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but I needed the same thing and found this. All you are missing is pictureBox1.Refresh(); inside your loop. The new image doesn't show up until the picture box is refreshed